# Strange behaviour of SequenceInputStream

Tags: encoding, inputstream, sequence

I tried to create a SequenceStream of  UTF-16 encoded files.

```
public class sequenceStream {


public static void main(String[] args) {        
    try {

        File f1 = new File("C:\\Temp\\sequence1.txt");
        File f2=  new File("C:\\Temp\\sequence2.txt");
        File f3=  new File("C:\\Temp\\sequence3.txt");
        InputStream is = getSequencedInputStream(f1,f2,f3);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-16"));

        String line;
        int count=0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
            count++;
            System.out.println(count + " : " + line);
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }


}


private static InputStream getSequencedInputStream(File ... files)  {
    Vector v = new Vector(files.length);
    for (int i=0; i<files.length;i++){
        if(files[i].exists()){
            try {
                v.add(new FileInputStream(files[i]));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {     
            }
        }


    }
    return new SequenceInputStream(v.elements());
}
```

}

if i run this i got this as output:

```
1 : first file, first line
2 : first file, second line?second file, first line
3 : second file, second line?third file, first line
4 : third file, second line
```

if i run it, with only one File it works fine:

```
InputStream is = getSequencedInputStream(f1);
```

output:

```
1 : first file, first line
2 : first file, second line
```

Where are the Questionsmarks from? how can i handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with the termination of your files. Is there a newline after the last line, for instance?